# iptables drop length and TTL condition doesn't work

Tags: linux, unix, networking, ping, iptables

With iptables utility on Linux host need to create mini firewall.
I need to drop all incoming connections with package length greater than 722 AND TTL greater than 22. Need exactly AND. Drop only if both conditions are TRUE.

```
sudo iptables -N LOGDROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m ttl --ttl-gt 22 -j LOGDROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m ttl --ttl-gt 22 -j LOGDROP
sudo iptables -A LOGDROP -m length --length 722:65535 -j DROP
```

IP-adress of host is `10.6.7.9` with firewall.

I did 4 test from this host, trying to ping another host:

```
ping -s 10000 -t 250 10.6.7.10 //fail (TTL AND LENGHT are wrong)
ping -s 100 -t 200 10.6.7.10 //success (TTL is wrong)
ping -s 10 -t 10 10.6.7.10 //success (Both are right)
ping -s 10000 -t 10 10.6.7.10 // fail, BUT SHOULD BE TRUE.
```

Why last ping doesn't work ,and how to fix it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the reply path.

With `ping -t` you will only change the TTL for the packets that you are sending.
The reply packets will have a starting TTL set to the OS default (64 in Linux).

So in the forth case your outgoing packets will have a TTL of 10 and a size of ~10000. The packets that are coming back form 10.6.7.10 will have a TTL of 64 and a size of ~10000 and thus will be dropped.

You can use a sniffer, for example [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), to verify this.

Comment: With -t option I set TTL. It's not a default value.

Comment: You can change the TTL for the packet you *send*. But the machine that sends the *reply* will use the OS default TTL. You can verify that by using a sniffer such as wireshark. Disable or change (to 64 for example) the DROP rule in the OUTPUT chain and you will see that it works.

Comment: Oh, i mixed up the direction. You ARE sending from the machine with the firewall. I will rephrase my answer, but the problem remains. The incoming packets will have a TTL >22.